# Print path of output from python setup.py sdist

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

Is there way to get the path of the tar file that `setup.py sdist` built? I know where it is, but I'm looking to script it without having to `ls dist/` etc. I'm ok to override the command too if theres a variable that distutils assigns it too, or a function that will return it.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you can do:

```
python setup.py sdist --formats=gztar
FNAME=dist/`python setup.py --fullname`.tar.gz
echo $FNAME
```

Using the formats parameter to ensure that the file is going to be tar.gz
Have checked this script on a setup.py with setup from setuptools. Should work with distutils too.
You can override the dist folder, have a look at:

```
python setup.py sdist --help
```